# creating a jquery plugin on the jquery core $ object

Tags: jquery, plugins

I would like to create a plugin for jquery that doesn't work with the dom. I therefore don't need to use a jquery object from the $ function. I would like to make my own function called

```
$.shortcut(keys,action)
```

Icould probably just go

```
$.prototype.shortcut = function(){//my code}
```

but I would like to know if that's the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just about have it already...

```
$.shortcut = function(keys, action) {
    // code
}
```

I prefer to wrap mine in an anon function and pass jQuery as a param though. It helps avoid naming conflicts and makes for easier minification.

```
(function($){
    $.shortcut = function(keys, action) {
        // code
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This would also work best in a closure. This way you can reference the jQuery object as $ and know that it will work with `noConflict`: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `.prototype` part, and then it'll the way it's usually done. (except usually you use `jQuery` instead of `$` in case the person is using `noConflict`)